# Data gets deleted after closing the app [IOS]

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data

I wrote an ios application in order to save a data to core data and then fetch it with the following code:

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error;

NSManagedObject *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserData"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
[failedBankInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"userId"];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"UserData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
     NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"userId"]);

}
```

There no problem in here. But After I close my application and modify  the setvalue to 2, I only receive the last data which is 2. Earlier data (1) gets deleted.

What should I do to keep the data entries even after I close my application.

Thank You!

Comment: Try to save context after inserting new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `UIManagedDocument` to save the Core Data information.  I usually create the `UIManagedDocument` as a property of the class.  For the example I have created a `UIManagedDocument` called `theManagedDocument`:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DocumentName"];

self.theManagedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]])
{
    [theManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        if(success) [self documentIsReady];
        if(!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't Open Document");
    }];
}
else 
{
    [theManagedDocument saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
        if(success) [self documentIsReady];
        if(!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't Create Document");
    }];
}
```

Then I create a method called `documentIsReady` that is called when the document has been successfully created or opened (opened if it is already present, created otherwise).  I will also keep the context as a property.  Here it is called `context`.  I also added in your code:

```
- (void) documentIsReady
{
    if(self.theManagedDocument.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) 
    {
        self.context = self.theManagedDocument.managedObjectContext;
        NSError *error;

        NSManagedObject *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserData"
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
        [failedBankInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"userId"];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                           entityForName:@"UserData" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"userId"]);
        }
    }
}
```

You will then want to close the document when you are done using:

```
[self.theManagedDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
    if(success) NSLog(@"Closed Successfully");
    if(!success) NSLog(@"Error Closing Document");
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, where should i create theManagedDocument as UIManagedDocument?

Comment: I created it as a property of the `ViewController` or `AppDelegate`, or whatever `class` you are making the call in.

Answer (score 1):

You did not save your new record.

```
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: Yes suprisingly this one line of code worked for my problem. But how this line of code differs from the above solution? Do you see any drawbacks of using this solution instead of the prev one? Thank You!

Comment: The `save` command actually writes all the changes in the managed object context to the database. If you do not call `save`, the changes will not be saved. It's as simple as that. If this helped you, you should tick the check mark for the answer.

Comment: This was my issue.  Thanks for the simple solution. +1